# Using the returned value of an ordinary function insdie a ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an ordinary JavaScript function like this:

```js
// frontend/src/static/js/components/daw/index.js

export default function Daw() {
  return (
    <>
        <div>Hello world.</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm trying to use the above function inside the below ReactJS component:

```js
// frontend/src/static/js/pages/_VideoMediaPage.js

import React from 'react';
import Daw from '../components/daw';

export class Page extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>{Daw()}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

[image: Error screenshot]

## Question

What's the proper way to use the ordinary function inside the ReactJS component?

Comment: You've left something out in your code. Where's the hook that this error message is talking about?

Comment: @Thomas The `hook` error got resolved by @yousoumar answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is technically a React Functional Component. You should be calling it like one.

```
import React from 'react';
import Daw from '../components/daw';

export class Page extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div><Daw/></div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```